# How to update fetched data to view next or previous page - Paginated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pagination

I am fetching data from a API,then displaying it to the page. I have achieved that,

Now I want to build a next and previous button to render the next page of information.

One of the data returned is metadata to links that can be attached to the base url. I got the data and updated it in my state as:

```
articlePages: []
```

the data is structured as :

```
 "metadata": {
            "pagination": {
                "next_page": "/api/articles/ios_index?page=2",
                "current_page": "/api/articles/ios_index?page=1",
                "previous_page": "/api/articles/ios_index?page=0"
            }
        }
```

**How should I build the functions for previous and next, so that they attach the right string to the base url, then fetch the new data?**

Here is the response I receive then I update my state:

Response Format:

```
"metadata": {
        "pagination": {
            "next_page": "/api/articles/ios_index?page=2",
            "current_page": "/api/articles/ios_index?page=1",
            "previous_page": "/api/articles/ios_index?page=0"
        }
    }


 "data" :{
            "id": 713,
            "url": "https:sample.-sale",
            "title": "The World According to Eddie Huang",
            "published_at": "2017-08-29T04:00:00.000Z",
            "published": true,
            "hero": "https://d1qz9pzgo5wm5k./CPG9crJHRqSPKQg9jymd",
            "listings": [],
            "tag_list": [
                "eddie-huang",
                "television"
            ],
            "franchise": "The Drop",
            "slug": "eddie-huang-interview-sale",
            "author": "Lawrence Schlossman",
            "content_type": "long",
            "position": "feature"
        }
```

Here is a snippet of my code, any help is appreciated :

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class ArticleApi extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      blogs: "",
      articlePages: []
    }
  }


fetchData = () => {
    axios.get(`https:sample.sale/api/articles/ios_index`)
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({
          blogs: res.data.data,
          blogPages: res.data.metadata
        })
      })
      .catch(error => {
        return ('Looks like there was a problem: \n', error);
      });
  }


componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData()
  }


previousPage = () => {
      axios.get(`https:sample.sale/api/articles/ios_index${this.state.blogPages.pagination.previous_page}`)
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({
          blogs: res.data.data,
          blogPages: res.data.metadata
        })
      })
      .catch(error => {
        return (error);
      });
}

nextPage = () => {
      axios.get(`https:sample.sale/api/articles/ios_index${this.state.blogPages.pagination.next_page}`)
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({
          blogs: res.data.data,
          blogPages: res.data.metadata
        })
      })
      .catch(error => {
        return (error);
      });
}

render() {
   let feed = "Loading...";
      if (this.state.blogs) {
        feed = this.state.blogs.map((ele, idx) => {
          return (
             <div key={idx} >
                <div className="articleContent">
                  <p><strong>{ele.franchise}</strong></p>
                  <h1 className="title"> {ele.title}</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
      })
    }
return (
      <div>
        <h3 FEED</h3>
         {feed}
          <button onClick={this.previousPage}>Previous Page</button>
           <button onClick={this.nextPage}>Next Page</button>
       </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Please update your post to include a question, it is unclear what you need help with

Comment: @MitchLillie I Mitch,just updated my question. Is it clearer ? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

At present you are building a strange URL for both the next and previous page functions:

```
axios.get(`https:sample.sale/api/articles/ios_index${this.state.blogPages.pagination.next_page}`)

// but this.state.blogPages.pagination.next_page is equal to "/api/articles/ios_index?page=2", right? 
// So if we replace the variable with its value, your url actually looks something like this:

axios.get('https:sample.sale/api/articles/ios_index/api/articles/ios_index?page=2')
```

The correct call should look like:

```
axios.get(`https:sample.sale${this.state.blogPages.pagination.next_page}`)
```

And similarly for previous page.